# Formula to extract the data within the second/consecutive parentheses

Tags: microsoft-excel

From the below i want to extract the data between the parenthesis if it is only number.

Nissan - X-Trail Launch (May) (Jun) - SO9158518 (65124817)
Tourism - Curious 2017 (News) (44124469)

Comment: Hello, can you explain more what you are trying to do? Here is a link that may help : https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/10/07/excel-find-search-functions/#Excel-FIND-formula-example4

Comment: Do you want to extract ***65124817***  ??

Comment: your title is somewhat contradictory to the description. What is your expected output? Also could you share a bit more examples?

Answer (score 0):

Try this User Defined Function:

```
Public Function parens(t As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, L As Long, CH As String
    Dim x As String, y As String, temp As String
    Dim ary() As String, Kapture As Boolean, a As Variant
    Dim j As Long

    parens = ""
    L = Len(t)
    x = "("
    y = ")"
    Kapture = False
    temp = ""
    j = 1

    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(t, i, 1)
        If CH = x Then
            Kapture = True
            temp = ""
            ReDim Preserve ary(1 To j)
            j = j + 1
        ElseIf CH = y Then
            ary(UBound(ary)) = temp
        Else
            If Kapture Then temp = temp & CH
        End If
    Next i

    For Each a In ary
        If IsNumeric(a) Then
            parens = a
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

[image]

It extracts parenthetical material until it finds a numeric value.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=parens(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**